# PHP MYSQLI queries

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

So I have 2 tables in the same database, and they are linked to each other by a variable. How can I get a piece of information from one table and use that to select everything from the other table that has that value?

```
$term = $_REQUEST["term"];

$films = array();

if (isset($term)) {

    $sqlFilms = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE title LIKE '%" . $term . "%'";

} else {

    $sqlFilms = "SELECT * FROM `films`";

}

$resultFilms = mysqli_query($link, $sqlFilms);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultFilms, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $films[] = Array("id" => $row["id"],
        "title" => $row["title"],
        "poster" => $row["poster"],
        "description" => $row["description"],
        "director" => $row["director"]);
};
```

This code works fine, and I can access all "films" that have $term in the title. But if I search for a genre, which is a different table but has a variable called "film_id" which is equal to the "id" of the film its associated with, I either get all the films or no films. This is the code to try a film by genre.

```
$genreFilms = array();
$stuff = array();

if (isset($term)) {

    $sqlGenreFilmIDs = "SELECT film_id FROM genres WHERE genre LIKE '%" . $term . "%'";

    $resultGenres = mysqli_query($link, $sqlGenreFilmIDs);

    $sqlGenreFilms = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE id LIKE '%" . $stuff["film_id"] . "%'";

} else {

    $sqlGenreFilms = "SELECT * FROM `films`";

}

$resultGenreFilms = mysqli_query($link, $sqlGenreFilms);


while ($genrerow = mysqli_fetch_array($resultGenreFilms, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $genreFilms[] = Array("id" => $genrerow["id"],
        "title" => $genrerow["title"],
        "poster" => $genrerow["poster"],
        "description" => $genrerow["description"],
        "director" => $genrerow["director"]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the films you search for to the genre, you should use sql join or subqueries. For example,

```
$sqlGenreFilms = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE id in (SELECT film_id from genres WHERE genre LIKE '%" . $term . "%')"
```

Note that for more advanced queries you should really read up on SQL language and how it works.

And in any case you   definitely should read, why quoting variables into query text like you do, is considered extremely harmful from security perspective. Google for "sql injection".

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the heads up about reading up on SQL, I'm in a class for PHP and we're just breaching the subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($term)) {
    $sqlGenreFilms = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE id in (SELECT film_id FROM genres WHERE genre LIKE '%" . $term . "%')";
    // if you want genre info and films info together use join
    //$sqlGenreFilms = "SELECT genres.*, films.* FROM genres left outer join films on genres.film_id = films.id WHERE genres.genre LIKE '%" . $term . "%')";
} else {
    $sqlGenreFilms = "SELECT * FROM `films`";
}
```

Comment: You can approve my answer if not any issues.. :)